# Separating a file by lines in python

Tags: python

I have a .fastq file (cannot use Biopython) that consists of multiple samples in different lines.  The file contents look like this:

```
@sample1
ACGTC.....
+
IIIIDDDDDFF
@sample2
AGCGC....
+
IIIIIDFDFD
.
.
.
@sampleX
ACATAG
+
IIIIIDDDFFF
```

I want to take the file and separate out each individual set of samples (i.e. lines 1-4, 5-8 and so on until the end of the file) and write each of them to a separate file (i.e. sample1.fastq contains that contents of sample 1 lines 1-4 and so on).  Is this doable using loops in python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580657/how-to-read-a-fasta-file-in-python

Comment: You could read and or copy/paste the source code of the FASTA parser from Biopython https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/301498dbdfa413cb14891e7a904d9635a63237b5/Bio/SeqIO/FastaIO.py#L188

Comment: I am not allowed to use Biopython.  I will try to modify the code from thestackoverflow link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultdict and regex for this

```py
import re
from collections import defaultdict

# Get file contents
with open("test.fastq", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

samples = defaultdict(list) # Make defaultdict of empty lists
identifier = ""

# Iterate through every line in file
for line in content.split("\n"):
    # Find strings which start with @
    if re.match("^@.*", line):
        # Set identifier to match following lines to this section
        identifier = line.replace("@", "")
    else:
        # Add the line to its identifier
        samples[identifier].append(line)
```

Now all you have to do is save the contents of this default dictionary into multiple files:

```py
# Loop through all samples (and their contents)
for sample_name, sample_items in samples.items():
    # Create new file with the name of its sample_name.fastq
    # (You might want to change the naming)
    with open(f"{sample_name}.fastq", "w") as f:
        # Write each element of the sample_items to new line
        f.write("\n".join(sample_items))
```

It might be helpful for you to also include `@sample_name` in the beginning of the file (first line), but I'm not sure you want that so I haven't added that.

*Note that you can adjust the regex settings to only match `@sample[number]` instead of all `@...`, if you want that, you can use `re.match("^@sample\d+")` instead*